# only one select box shows up due to duplicate id

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html-select, jquery-chosen

I have a form where there can be three select boxes depending upon a checkbox - I'm using jQuery to show/hide them depending on which checkbox is active.  Below, `f` is `player`

```
<% Game.all.each_with_index do |game, i| %>
  <div class="team_<%= i %> hide">
    <%= f.collection_select(:team_division_id, TeamDivision.where("game_id = ?", game.id), 
                            :id, :name, include_blank: true) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Each collection select is generating an id of `player_team_division_id` - and since there can be only one id a page, this is really screwing with my results, namely the first select box shows up fine, but the others show up as simple links to `javascript:void(0)` - if I check out the generated divs with firebug/chrome, the information is there, it just isn't showing up as a select box (presumably) because of the id.  I'm using chosen.js, if that makes a difference, although I'm don't think this has any affect.

**Edit (Models)**:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :team_division, touch: true
end

class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
  has_many :team_divisions
end

Class TeamDivision < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
  belongs_to :game
end
```

Comment: I think you can change :id in collection_select parameters to some variable that will be unique for the view. Eg, combination of game.id and team_division_id. And you really shouldn't have stuff like TeamDivision.where in your view. I'm sure there will be much better solution to your problme. Can you post your models (Game, Player, Team and TeamDivision) relationships? I'm think, in this case, it would be better to go without collection_select, but I cannot be sure until I know relationships...

Comment: Hi, @MarekTakac - Thanks for your comment.  I'm planning to move this into a helper (actually I have another question going about that - but I changed gears slightly).  Please see my updated question.